# Can I add multiple users to qemu.config?

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, qemu

I am installing my first KVM/QEMU based virt manager. As per the instruction one needs to change the config file of qemu.config.

`sudo nano /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf`

I used **vim** to edit the file and added a new user as described below. However, while doing so I had to edit (remove) the "root" user.

I wonder if one can add both the user and root in this config file like so

`user = "username" "root"`
`group = ''username" "root"`

This way one can access the program as root as well as a user (?)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it.
just add `user = "neo" "root"`